# How To Migrate Existing Azure Assets to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

Can existing Azure assets, i.e. cloud services, notification hubs, SQL servers and databases, storage accounts and service buses be migrated to a Azure App Service? If so, how?

Comment: Refer these https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/migration-checklist-when-moving-to-azure-app-service/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/introducing-azure-websites-migration-assistant/ and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting checklist, especially if dealing with migrating on-premise assets to Azure. But what about internal Azure assets? Should they be treated as on-premise? I.e. I have an existing web-site on Azure. Should I point the Azure Websites Migration Assistant to it?

Comment: The Azure App Service (Mobile Service App) can use an existing Notification Hub. Using the "Push" setting, you can select a hub within the same resource group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Azure App Service (Mobile Service App) can use an existing Notification Hub. Using the "Push" setting, you can select a hub within the same resource group.

For Azure App Services, when you configure the notification hub for your app service, you could choose an existing Notification Hub. **Note:** You could choose an existing notification hub across different resource groups and under different locations. Moreover, when you add a new hub under "SETTINGS > Push" of your app service on Azure Portal, it would create a new notification hub within the same resource group for your app service and the location for the new hub would use the location of your resource group. I would recommend you follow [Azure Resource Manager overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview) and [Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview) for a better understanding of Resource Group and App service plan.

> Can existing Azure assets, i.e. cloud services, notification hubs, SQL servers and databases, storage accounts and service buses be migrated to a Azure App Service?

For cloud services, I just found [migrate an cloud services to service fabric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/service-fabric/migrate-from-cloud-services) and [migrate the web application to cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service). AFAIK, if you want to migrate your cloud services application to azure app service, you need to adjust your project and deploy it to your app service.

For SQL servers and databases, storage accounts and service buses, you just need to change the connection string for the specific services when communicating with them programmatically in your app service. Moreover, in order to reduce the latency between your app service with other azure services, you need to make sure they are in the same data center or closer to each other.